# Python read/write

Tags: python, sorting, file-io

My program must read in a file of text which has many lines. It then copies the 
same text to an output file, except that all the useless words such as "the", "a", and "an" are removed. What is the problem?

```
f=open("a.txt","r")
inp=f.readlines()
f.close()
out=open("a.txt","w")
stopList=['the','a','an']
for i in inp:
    if i in stopList:
        out.write(i)
out.close()
```

Comment: `"a.txt"` will have the initial+the appended lines since you don't clear the file. Not sure if that's important. Besides can you tell us what are the **symptoms of the problem**, i.e. what is happening instead of what you'd like to happen?

Comment: You have a list of all the lines in your file. You are iterating through the list checking if a line is in stopList which contains just the three words, 'the', 'a', 'an'. Something is wrong here don't you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here ya go, just use `str.replace`:

```
with open("a.txt","r") as fin, open("b.txt","w") as fout:
    stopList=['the','a','an']
    for line in fin:
        for useless in stopList:
            line = line.replace(useless+' ', '')
         fout.write(line)
```

If you don't want to store the whole file to memory, you need to write the result somewhere else. But if you don't mind, you can rewrite it:

```
with open("a.txt","r") as fin, open("a.txt","w") as fout:
    stopList=['the','a','an']
    r = []
    for line in fin:
        for useless in stopList:
            line = line.replace(useless+' ', '')
        r.append(line)
    fout.writelines(r)
```

Demo:

```
>>> line = 'the a, the b, the c'
>>> stopList=['the','a','an']
>>> for useless in stopList:
    line = line.replace(useless+' ', '')


>>> line
'a, b, c'
```

Comment: @alKid it copies three times one element

Comment: What do you mean by "three times one element"?

Comment: @alKid for example it writes word "ABC" 3 times such as "ABC ABC ABC"

Comment: Oh, whoops! Sorry about that. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Using [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
import re

with open('a.txt') as f, open('b.txt','w') as out:
    stopList = ['the', 'a', 'an']
    pattern = '|'.join(r'\b{}\s+'.format(re.escape(word)) for word in stopList)
    pattern = re.compile(pattern, flags=re.I)
    out.writelines(pattern.sub('', line) for line in f)

# import shutil
# shutil.move('b.txt', 'a.txt')
```